# grid.arrange with ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I was wondering if there is a workaround to get the layout of the plots that we get using grid.arrange using ggplotly.

The resulting object from grid.draw is not a ggplot object obviously. So, wondering for any workarounds to pass the following plot to ggplotly.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

p1 = qplot(1:20,1:20)
p2 = qplot(1:20, 20:1)

grid.arrange(p1,p2, ncol=2)
```

Comment: Yep. By creating a container HTML document with the desired CSS grid layout and embedding each separate plotly HTML output in those grid sections using iframes. alternately, using an R markdown with a similar grid structure or embed the plotly plots into grid areas in an R markdown flexdashboard

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(plotly)

p1 = qplot(1:20,1:20)
p2 = qplot(1:20, 20:1)

ply1 <- ggplotly(p1)
ply2 <- ggplotly(p2)

subplot(ply1, ply2, nrows=1)
```