# Axis labels lost in plotly::subplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

Continuing the example introduced in
[grid.arrange with ggplotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813158/grid-arrange-with-ggplotly)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(plotly)

d <- data.frame(x=1:20,y=1:20, z=20:1)
p1 <- ggplot(data=d) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  xlab("X") + ylab("Y")
p2 <- ggplot(data=d) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=z)) +
  xlab("X") + ylab("Z")
ggplotly(p1)
ggplotly(p2)
```

Axis labels are lost with subplot:

```
ggplotly(p1)
ggplotly(p2)
ply1 <- ggplotly(p1)
ply2 <- ggplotly(p2)
subplot(ply1, ply2, nrows=1)
```

How could I actually keep axis labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `titleY` and `titleX` in your `subplot` to add the labels. With `margin` you could add some whitespace between the plots like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(plotly)

d <- data.frame(x=1:20,y=1:20, z=20:1)
p1 <- ggplot(data=d) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  xlab("X") + ylab("Y")
p2 <- ggplot(data=d) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=z)) +
  xlab("X") + ylab("Z")

ply1 <- ggplotly(p1)
ply2 <- ggplotly(p2)
subplot(ply1, ply2, nrows=1, 
        titleY = TRUE, 
        titleX = TRUE,
        margin = 0.05)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>